# Networkdays Negative Number

Tags: excel

I can't figure out how not to display a negative value when i use Network days.

A1: Completion Date
A2: Oldest Sig Date
a3: 5 Business Days
B1:Completion Date Value 
B2: Oldest Sig Date Value
B3: Formula

I need to calculate the difference between A1 & A2, -1 (because i can't count the first day).

Here is my current formula, in B3.
=NETWORKDAYS(C24,C25,Holidays)-1

I tried the following if statement but it is still showing me a -1
=IF(NETWORKDAYS(F1,F2,Holidays)-1>=0,"0",NETWORKDAYS(F1,F2,Holidays)-1).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: also, your operator is the wrong way around, surely you want "<=" instead of ">=" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MAX` function to limit the result to 0 at the lowest, i.e.

`=MAX(0,NETWORKDAYS(C24,C25,Holidays)-1)`